# CORS error when accessing NodeJS express api in Docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, express, docker-compose

I have NodeJS api and NextJS application in Separate docker containers when I'm in host machine its working fine, but when I'm running inside docker containers its giving CORS error.

My express config in **API**

```
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000/' // Allowing front-end running port 3000
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(json());
app.enable("trust proxy");
app.use(methodOverride());
```

In front-end **APP NextJS axios config**

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:4000/', withCredentials: true });
```

[image]

[image]

Its woking fine when im running API from host machine, with same configuration its giving CORS error in Docker.

Comment: You have the cors origin set to different port then the one it actualy runs on. So if your app is accessible at port 4000 then the origin in app.use must be 4000. I assume you are exposing port 3000 from your docker container as port 4000 on the host machine. So simply expose 3000 as 3000. Include you dockerfile if that is not the case.

Comment: API Docker file

"""
FROM node:alpine

EXPOSE 4000

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm uninstall bcrypt
RUN npm install bcrypt
CMD ["node", "build/app.js"]
"""

Comment: Hm, i did not realize you have frontend running on port 3000 and backend on port 4000. Try adding this header `Access-Control-Allow-Private-Network: true` in your express app.

Comment: This sounds more like a docker configuration error to me. I assume you actually have two containers and that the frontend of the nextjs application is directly invoking the nodejs container, right? If so, please share the Dockerfiles and eventually the docker-compose if you are using any. In my opinion the problem is rather that localhost:4000 is unreachable, hence the CORS error, which does not really depend on any config or so. Also, the command you use to start the containers is useful as well in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see your API configuration seems correct, but in your NextJS create pages/api/whatever.js and call your API from handler

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

export default async function handler(req, res){
   try {
     const response = axios.post('http://localhost:4000/<your_login_api_URL>', req.body)
   }catch(error) {
     // handle error here
   }

}
```

this will work and its safer way to mask your back end API calls from front end.

Answer (score 0):

Add each `localhost` + `port` to the `cors` options (*I left some other options just for example, not relevant to your question though*):

```
//options for cors midddleware
const options: cors.CorsOptions = {
    allowedHeaders: [
        'X-ACCESS_TOKEN',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
        'Authorization',
        'Origin',
        'x-requested-with',
        'Content-Type',
        'Content-Range',
        'Content-Disposition',
        'Content-Description',
    ],
    credentials: true,
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    origin: [
        'http://localhost:5001',
        'http://localhost:50000',
    ],
    preflightContinue: false,
};

const app = express();

const corsOpts = cors(options);

//add cors middleware
app.use(corsOpts);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is common issue many solutions.

The correct solution depends on your requirements.The simpler solution is to run the docker container with NGINX acting as reverse proxy.

**Example of nginx docker**

```
FROM nginx:alpine

WORKDIR /etc/nginx
COPY ./nginx.conf ./conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT [ "nginx" ]
CMD [ "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

**Build it as cors**

```
docker build -t cors .
```

**Finally make sure that nginx.conf allowing origins from request**

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
```

**Example of nginx.config**

```
upstream api {
  # Could be host.docker.internal - Docker for Mac/Windows - the host itself
  # Could be your API in a appropriate domain
  # Could be other container in the same network, like container_name:port
  server url:port;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,
      X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'application/json';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      return 204;
    }

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,
    X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';

    proxy_pass http://api/;
  }
}
```

Comment: The nextjs application already exposes the running application on a port, there is no need to have an extra nginx reverse proxy if you use nextjs as far as I know. The problem might rather be that port forwarding is missing in docker, hence the container is not reachable.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to your `package.json` file. then rebuild your container and start the app.

```json
"proxy": "http://localhost:4000",
```